# How to draw a circle in UILabel?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-graphics, uilabel

I want to do some thing like this,
[image: option image]

How to draw a circle in UILabel which looks similar to this image, i just want to avoid using an image instead.

Comment: Use the Unicode character for the circled A - Ⓐ

Comment: What exactly you want t do? elaborate a litle you wand to have a symbol or want every other char circled now and then etc?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd suggest adding a shape layer to the UILabel. Something like this:

```
// Create the shape layer

CAShapeLayer *circleLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
circleLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)].CGPath;
circleLayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
circleLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
circleLayer.lineWidth = 1;

// Add it do your label's layer hierarchy

[label.layer addSublayer:circleLayer];
```

That'll give you the greatest control over its appearance and that of the font for the A.

UPDATE:

It's just occurred to me that you'll struggle to get the "A" vertically offset in order to put a circle around it. There are hacks to get vertical centering in a UILabel, but you'd be much better off using a UITextField instead, since it supports the contentVerticalAlignment property. You just need to set its userInteractionEnabled to NO to prevent user from typing text on it!

Other than that, the principle of adding the CAShapeLayer is the same.

Comment: This code does not compile. The first 3 lines are all incorrect: assigning a UIBezierPath to a CAShapeLayer and assigning UIColors to CGColorRefs.

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this by the way @maddy suggested or, create `UILabel` with square rect, put text alignment to the middle and use label's layer's `cornerRadius` with `borderWidth`. Just set `cornerRadius`to the half width (or height) of the label. Good Luck!

Comment: From my experience, this results in an awkward diamond-ish shape rather than the desired circular shape.